# Sum of odd numbers

Tags: java, sum

You are given the sum 1 - 3 + 5 - 7 + 9 - 11 + 13... You should compile a program that (given integer N) finds and displays the value of the sum to the N-th addend.

I don't even have an idea how this program should be. I've written some code but  don't know what to add. Please, can you help me? :)

Here is my code:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.print("n = ");
int n = input.nextInt();
int sum = 0;

for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {       
    if (i % 2 != 0) {
        sum = sum + i;
    }
}

System.out.println(sum);
```

Comment: `sum = sum + i` - you seem to have missed the negatives.

Comment: @BoristheSpider Yeah, that is my main problem

Comment: You can get it directly with `sum = n % 2 == 0 ? -n : n`

Comment: Also note that `1 - 3 + 5 - 7 + 9 - 11 + 13 ... = 1 + (5 - 3) + (9 - 7) + (13 - 11) ... = 1 + 2 + 2 + 2 ...`.

Comment: Given `n := 4` is the answer suppoed to be `1-3 = -2` or `1-3+5-7 = -4`?

Comment: @BoristheSpider Thank you! I will try to think about your suggestion :)

Comment: Guys, the results are 1, -2, 3, -4, 5, -6 and so on. It's just `n` with every even number being negative.

Comment: @RobinKoch The first one

Comment: @dasblinkenlight A math based solution would be `return math.pow(-1, n%2+1)*n` (for n given the number of summands which is not the assignment accoriding to Anna)

Comment: `-n * (1-2*(n&1))`. Don't use that if you don't understand it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be you want this

If I enter **i/p 7** this will produce **-4 as o/p**

```
for (int i = 1; i <= n; i+=2) {
        if( i % 4 == 1 )
            sum = sum + i;
        else
            sum = sum - i;
}
```

in  @fafl style (Using Ternary operator), correct me if I'm wrong

```
sum += (i % 2 != 0) ? ( i % 4 == 1 ) ? + i : - i;
```

If I enter **i/p 7** this will produce **7 as o/p**

```
        int n = input.nextInt();
        int sum = 0;
        int addOrDedduct = 1;
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++ ) {
                if( addOrDedduct % 4 == 1 )
                    sum = sum + addOrDedduct;
                else
                    sum = sum - addOrDedduct;
                addOrDedduct+=2;
        }
        System.out.println(sum);
```

**Update:**
fafl's statement `sum = n % 2 == 0 ? -n : n` producing same o/p, Here you don't need to use `loop`
Forget about the loop and use fafl's answer.

Comment: @shantaram_t It works!!! Thank you! But I have a question: why i % 4 == 1?

Comment: bcoz `( i % 4 == 1 )`  gives you no. to be add e.g.  `1 = ( i%4 == 1)`  , `5 = ( i%4 == 1)` , `9 = ( i%4 == 1)`  and so on and rest of the numbers  i.e. `i%2 != 0` e.g `3 = ( i%2 != 1)` , `7 = ( i%2 != 1)` you are substracting

Comment: @AnnaNikolova I have removed condition checking `(i % 2 != 0)` since incrementing loop by `i+=2`

Comment: @dasblinkenlight sir, you are taking it as wrong, you can correct me If I'm wrong

Comment: @dasblinkenlight sir, I have given answer...check and let me know

Comment: @dasblinkenlight  no issue sir, because of My bad English I did not got your previous comment, that you explained

Comment: I think the point that [fafl was making](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41506150/sum-of-odd-numbers/41506554#comment70217726_41506150) is that the sum of that series produces `1, -2, 3, -4, 5` as the result so you don't need a loop or anything like that, you need to return `n`, multiplied by `-1` if `n` is even...

Comment: @BoristheSpider fafl's answer is short and sweet , I don't need to use loop for that

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with an extra variable to check if you have to add or to subtract:

```
    int sum = 0;
    boolean sub = false;
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        if (i % 2 == 1) {
            if (sub) {
                sum -= i;
                sub = false;
            } else {
                sum += i;
                sub = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

This solution is a bit hacky but it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Fafl is right with
sum = n % 2 == 0 ? -n : n

Comment: @BoristheSpider maby i didnt get the question but if n=3 and the answer is 3 because if u get the sum of :1 - 3 + 5 - 7 + 9 - 11 + 13... till the 3rd diggit u get 1-3+5=3

Comment: I think you are right; have a vote. But I think you need to explain your logic, then post code, then explain the code. Especially when answering a beginner's question.

Comment: OK ur right ;)
but she said that shantaram_t answer is right so i didnt get the question because it's not the same sum

Comment: I have a truly remarkable proof by induction of this which this comment is too small to contain.

Answer (score 0):

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter n= ");
    int n = input.nextInt();
    int sum=0;
    boolean positive=false;

    for(int i=1;i<=n;i+=2){
        positive=!positive;
        sum = positive? sum+i : sum-i; 
    }
    System.out.println(sum);
}
```

Comment: I would vote for either `int sign = -1` and `sum = sum + sign * i` or `sum = negative ? sum+i : sum-i`, you don't need to test a boolean against `true`.

Comment: If you ever find yourself writing `positive == true`, i.e. testing a `boolean` against `true`, then you have gone wrong somewhere along the line.

Comment: That's true. I changed it.

Answer (score 0):

Using a for-loop, no modulo arithmitic:

```java
int sum = 0
for (int i = 1; math.abs(i) <= n; i = -math.signum(i)*(math.abs(i)+2)) {
        sum += i;
    }
system.out.println(sum)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to the below code, if you want.

```
package java.programs;
 
import java.util.*;
 
public class OddNumberSum {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int N, i, sum = 0;
 
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a number");
        N = in.nextInt();
 
        for(i = 0; i <= N; i++){
            if((i%2) == 1){
                sum += i;
            }
        }
     
        System.out.print("Sum of all odd numbers 
           between 0 to " + N + " = " + sum);
    }
}
```